# Why does this regex match on angular fail only on Safari?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, safari

I have the following code on my **angular** project. With Chrome and Firefox works well but in Safary causes and exception.

```
var shour = "9:00:00 PM CDT";
var ehour = "12:00:00 AM CDT";

var conver_shour = shour.match(/^(\d+):(\d+)/)[0] + shour.match(/[AP][M]$/)[0];
var conver_ehour = ehour.match(/^(\d+):(\d+)/)[0] + ehour.match(/[AP][M]$/)[0];

console.log("shour: " + conver_shour); // The answer should be 09:00PM
console.log("ehour: " + conver_ehour); // The answer should be 12:00AM
```

I try to run on **jsbin**, **plunkr** and **jsfiddle** but something fail and I cannot see what is the cause.

> This is the exception
>       Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'shour.match(/[AP][M]$/)') 
>       $eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js:142:467 
>       $apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js:143:193
>       https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-calendar/1.0.0/calendar.min.js:1:326
>       https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js:156:171

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does it really work in Chrome and Firefox? Seems to me the regex doesn't match, and then there is no array, but just `null` and as `null` is not an array, it can't be access with `[0]` ?

Comment: If you want the output to be `09:00PM`, the input will need to start with a `0` or otherwise you will need some extra string logic to put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex:

```
/[AP][M]$/
```

Is looking to find `AM` or `PM` at the end of the string... but those characters don't appear at the end of the string, so `match` returns `null`. Trying to do `null[0]` throws the exception.

You probably meant to use:

```
/[AP]M/
```

```js
var shour = "9:00:00 PM CDT";
var ehour = "12:00:00 AM CDT";

var conver_shour = shour.match(/^(\d+):(\d+)/)[0] + shour.match(/[AP]M/)[0];
var conver_ehour = ehour.match(/^(\d+):(\d+)/)[0] + ehour.match(/[AP]M/)[0];

console.log("shour: " + conver_shour); // The answer should be 09:00PM
console.log("ehour: " + conver_ehour); // The answer should be 12:00AM
```

Comment: Or maybe even `/\b[AP]M\b/` or `/\b[AP]\.?M\b\.?/i`

Comment: It works now changing the `/[AP][AM$/]` for `/[AP]M/` thanks for the answer @4castle.

Comment: As improvement I'd suggest to the author to before try to get `[0]` position of match, check if the match doesn't return `null`, otherwise it'll keep giving `Cannot read property '0' of null`.

Comment: I will improve the code with your suggestions @WiktorStribiżew, thank you.